# Limit Process.Start() attempts in .Net?

Tags: c#

So I have basic win form where you enter a username/password and it then tries to log in for you.

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
start.Verb = "runas";
start.UserName = uName;
start.Password = uPass;
start.Domain = "MyDomain";
start.UseShellExecute = false;
start.Arguments = "";
start.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe";
start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
start.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process proc = Process.Start(start);
```

All works nice and well except when a bad password is put in.  At that point, it appears that the process keeps attempting to start with the bad password **or that the process started keeps trying to launch the applications specified with the given credentials**, locking the user account due to too many failed attempts.  This isn't my code looping, one call from my code equals unending login attempts (well, until I stop the entire application).  There are no parameters that ProcessStartInfo users that would allow me to say 'try once only'.

So how do I limit it to only one attempt to start with a given password?

To expand on this because of the comments, I've put a breakpoint right on `start.CreateNoWindow = true;` which is hit only once.  I hit continue, after which, the next line throws an error saying the password is bad.  I hit continue again and the same line throws another error.  Perhaps it is better to say that their is one process making multiple attempts which I want to limit to a single attempt.

**EDIT:**

While this doesn't put a limit on the number of attempts made in a conventional manner, it does stop it after one failure.

Change

```
Process proc = Process.Start(start);
```

To

```
Process proc = null;
try
{
    proc = Process.Start(start);
}
catch (Win32Exception e)
{
    if(proc != null)
    {
        proc.Close();
    }
}
```

Of course, it should be spruced up to handle different errors appropriately, ect.

That the process exists even after the error is thrown makes me think that it Process.Start() successfully creates the process and it is the new process that keeps making login attempts.

I would still prefer some means to limit this in a more conventional manner.  I also worry this is not safe if one is spawning multiple processes this way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Process.Start() tries to start the process just once.. Maybe there's something else you're not showing?

Comment: You could put a breakpoint on `Process.Start` to see how many times it gets called.  Like @walther, I would expect to find that it's getting called more than once.

Comment: I put a breakpoint before it that wasn't hit even as the errors kept being given.  Maybe it isn't that the process is starting multiple times, but the one process started is making multiple attempts.

Comment: That sounds more likely.

Comment: To clarify, it was hit before the processed launched, but not between errors being given.  I'm guessing it keeps trying to log in, and I want to limit that.

Comment: We don't know anything about the process you're trying to launch, how are we supposed to help you?

Comment: @walther It is just launching an application the user specifies.  It can be any.  I've tested it with outlook and visual studio.  I'll add in the code for visual studio to the question.

Comment: As Lawtonfogle said, the credentials are perhaps given to te process (even if they are false), and each task initiated by the process, like reading a file, accessing a resource throws an incorrect password exception. Then the "too many attemps" error ?